# how i can execute a jQuery function after a time period when event fire in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, events, textbox, onkeyup

I want to fire a event on keyup of textbox 300 milisecond later

```
$("#blah").keyup(function () {
               //code is here
            }).delay(300).myfunction();
```

when i try to execute this function i found error that myfunction is not a function.

so can anyone explain how i can execute a function 300 milisecond later after keyup in a textbox

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
function myFunction () {
    // Code to do stuff after 300ms
}

$("#blah").keyup(function () {
               // Code to do stuff immediately
               setTimeout(myFunction, 300);
            });
```

Answer (score 8):

myfunction must be defined!

```
$("#blah").keyup(function () {

setTimeout(function(){
            myfunction();
         },300);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

As [docs](https://api.jquery.com/delay/) say, from version 1.4 on-wards, you can use `delay()` function

```
$( "#foo" ).slideUp( 300 ).delay( 800 ).fadeIn( 400 );
```